# How to combine conditions with the "or" operator using DolphinDB's "unifiedExpr"?

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dolphindb

I'm trying to utilize DolphinDB's `unifiedExpr` function to combine multiple conditions with the `or` operator. When I executed the following script:

```
data=table(1..6 as id1,7..12 as id2)
whereCodes = [<id1=2>,<id1=5>,<id2=12>]
delCodes=unifiedExpr(whereCodes,take(expr{,or,},whereCodes.size()-1))
sql(sqlCol("*"),data,delCodes).eval();
```

an error message was reported:

```
::evaluate(sql(sqlCol("*"), data, delCodes)) => Please use logical expressions to represent filtering criteria.
```

Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `or` operator within `unifiedExpr` without the need for the function `expr`.

```
data=table(1..6 as id1,7..12 as id2)
whereCodes = [<id1=2>,<id1=5>,<id2=12>]
delCodes=unifiedExpr(whereCodes,take(or,whereCodes.size()-1))
sql(sqlCol("*"),data,delCodes).eval();
```

Output:

```
id1 id2
2   8
5   11
6   12
```